# Some apps are too slow on my phone. What can I do to fix this?

Tags: applications, 7.0-nougat, lagging

Granted, at 2GB ram Mediatek MT6737, I don't have the fastest phone but why is it that I have 2 apps that are very sluggish while others are more, seemingly, graphic intensive yet much snappier? What can I do (besides the obvious - clean up the phone) to speed up these apps. I'm rooted.

Like this app:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.blockfolio.blockfolio

Answer (score 0):

Use any kernel tweaking app to speed up your processor
Some advanced tweaking apps will have "game mode" where it increases performance to max on running specific apps and returns to normal when apps are closed.

Comment: Thanks! Could you recommend any?

Comment: They are device specific - do some hunting :)